# Updating item in exist array laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I Have a products table has a column name images i store on it the names of all images after i upload them to server.

But my problem is when i want to update any products and i want add more pictures to the images column i got this error

```
Array to string conversion (SQL: update `products` set `pro_name` = Test, `images` = A6FC3-091547-2Nx.jpg, `updated_at` = 2018-06-17 03:29:20 where `id` = 1)
```

and this is my code:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id){

                $images=array();
                if($files=$request->file('images')){
                    foreach($files as $file){
                        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $fileName = str_random(5)."-".date('his')."-".str_random(3).".".$extension;
                        $upfolder = "admin/UploadImages"."/";
                        $file->move($upfolder , $fileName);
                        $images[]=$fileName;
                    }
                }


                $pros = Product::find($id);
                $pros->pro_name =   $request->input('pro_name');    
                $pros->pro_code =   $request->input('pro_code');    
                $pros->aval     =   $request->input('aval');    
                $pros->price    =   $request->input('price');   
                $pros->colors   =   $request->input('colors');  
                $pros->images   =   array_merge(explode(",",$pros->images), $images);
                $pros->cat_id   =   $request->input('cat_id');  
                $pros->hide     =   $request->input('hide');    
                $pros->save();
return redirect('products');
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said you are trying to store an array as a string. 
Using php's implode() function is where you need to be looking.

You can also looking into casts as mentioned before me.

*alternative way*

I am not sure why you are making this so complex for yourself. There may be a really obvious reason, however I can't see it.

Why don't you just create another model ProductImage with a pivot table product_product_image that way you can simply define a belongs to many relationship on both

Product

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

ProductImage

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

This way when you create a product

You can do something like:

```
$product = Product::create([
    //create your product here.
]);

foreach($request->images[] as $image){
    $product->images()->attach();    
}
```

Then when you are updating your images you can display them all within your page, maybe an ajax call that simple deletes an image when clicked on. Something that simply calls:

```
$product = Product::find($request->product_id);
$image = ProductImage::find($request->image_id);
$product->images()->detach($image);
```

This means that any you want to remove are already done before you post your whole product update back to the server.

Now you can simply add any new images to your product using the same functionality I posted for your create method.

Again, there may be a reason why you're doing it the way you are but I'm just showing you an alternative way that makes use of laravels functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method:

```
array_push($arrayName, Item1, [Item2, Item3]);
```

I think you have used, `$images[]=$fileName;` on 10th line, the LHS is an array and RHS is string value. Use, `array_push($images, $fileName);` instead.

In short I mean:

Replace your `$images[]=$fileName;` with `array_push($images, $fileName);`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$pros->images = array_merge(explode(",", $pros->images), $images);
```

`array_merge()` returns an array. It will try to convert that array to a string when you save the record, giving you the error you're seeing.

Based on your current logic, you'd need to implode the array after the merge:

```
$pros->images = implode(",", array_merge(explode(",",$pros->images), $images));
```

Now the string will be successfully saved to the database.

---

Another, Laravel specific, option would be to add your `images` fields to the `$casts` array on your `Product` model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'images' => 'array',
];
```

Now, the data will be stored in the database as a string, but Laravel will automatically cast it to an array whenever you access it.

If you updated your `$casts` attribute as above, your code would simply be:

```
$pros->images = array_merge($pros->images, $images);
```

If you have existing data in the database, you won't be able to simply make this change, since Laravel stores the array as json, not just a comma separated list, and your existing data would not be compatible. But, if this is new development, I'd suggest starting off with this method.